# Get the type of value using cty in hclwrite

Tags: go, terraform, hcl

am looking for a way to find the type of variable using [go-cty](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/zclconf/go-cty/cty) package in [hclwrite](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2/hclwrite).

My aim is to generate a variables file like below

```
variable "test_var" {
  val1 = bool
  val2 = string
  val3 = number
}
```

reference: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables

I am using the below code to generate this.

```
    vars := hclwrite.NewEmptyFile()
    vars_root_body := vars.Body()
    vars_file, vars_create_err := os.Create("variables.tf")
    logErrors(vars_create_err)
    vars_block := vars_root_body.AppendNewBlock("variable",[]string{"test_var"})
    vars_block_body := vars_block.Body()

    vars_block_body.SetAttributeValue("val", cty.Value{})

    _, vars_write_err := vars_file.Write(vars.Bytes())
    logErrors(vars_write_err)
    defer vars_file.Close()
```

the above code generates this

```
variable "test_var" {
  val = null
}
```

I want to fetch the type of that variable and set the attribute value based on that type, as show in the reference link above. I tried lot of ways but didn't get anything. Can someone please help me on this?

I tried the above code and lot of other ways like

```
cty.SetValEmpty(cty.Bool)
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Mart helps maintain that package (`go-cty`) and visits here occasionally, so I will defer to him to write a better answer than I would attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expected syntax for a `variable` block in Terraform includes an argument named `type`, not an argument named `val`. From your example I assume that you are intending to populate `type`.

The type constraint syntax that Terraform uses is not directly part of HCL and so there isn't any built-in way to generate that syntax in only one step. However, type constraint are built from HCL's identifier and function call syntaxes, and `hclwrite` does have some functions for helping to generate those as individual parts:

- [`TokensForIdentifier`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2/hclwrite#TokensForIdentifier)
- [`TokensForFunctionCall`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2/hclwrite#TokensForFunctionCall)

```
    f := hclwrite.NewEmptyFile()
    rootBody := f.Body()
    varBlock := rootBody.AppendNewBlock("variable", []string{"example"})
    varBody := varBlock.Body()
    varBody.SetAttributeRaw(
        "type",
        hclwrite.TokensForFunctionCall(
            "set",
            hclwrite.TokensForIdentifier("string"),
        ),
    )
    fmt.Printf("%s", f.Bytes())
```

The above will generate the following:

```
variable "example" {
  type = set(string)
}
```

If you already have a `cty.Value` value then you can obtain its type using the `Type` method. However, as mentioned above there isn't any ready-to-use function for converting a type into a type expression, so if you want to be able to generate a type constraint for any value then you'd need to write a function for this yourself, wrapping the `TokensForFunctionCall` and `TokensForIdentifier` functions. For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"

    "github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2/hclwrite"
    "github.com/zclconf/go-cty/cty"
)

func main() {
    f := hclwrite.NewEmptyFile()
    rootBody := f.Body()
    varBlock := rootBody.AppendNewBlock("variable", []string{"example"})
    varBody := varBlock.Body()
    varBody.SetAttributeRaw(
        "type",
        typeExprTokens(cty.Set(cty.String)),
    )
    fmt.Printf("%s", f.Bytes())
}

func typeExprTokens(ty cty.Type) hclwrite.Tokens {
    switch ty {
    case cty.String:
        return hclwrite.TokensForIdentifier("string")
    case cty.Bool:
        return hclwrite.TokensForIdentifier("bool")
    case cty.Number:
        return hclwrite.TokensForIdentifier("number")
    case cty.DynamicPseudoType:
        return hclwrite.TokensForIdentifier("any")
    }

    if ty.IsCollectionType() {
        etyTokens := typeExprTokens(ty.ElementType())
        switch {
        case ty.IsListType():
            return hclwrite.TokensForFunctionCall("list", etyTokens)
        case ty.IsSetType():
            return hclwrite.TokensForFunctionCall("set", etyTokens)
        case ty.IsMapType():
            return hclwrite.TokensForFunctionCall("map", etyTokens)
        default:
            // Should never happen because the above is exhaustive
            panic("unsupported collection type")
        }
    }

    if ty.IsObjectType() {
        atys := ty.AttributeTypes()
        names := make([]string, 0, len(atys))
        for name := range atys {
            names = append(names, name)
        }
        sort.Strings(names)

        items := make([]hclwrite.ObjectAttrTokens, len(names))
        for i, name := range names {
            items[i] = hclwrite.ObjectAttrTokens{
                Name:  hclwrite.TokensForIdentifier(name),
                Value: typeExprTokens(atys[name]),
            }
        }

        return hclwrite.TokensForObject(items)
    }

    if ty.IsTupleType() {
        etys := ty.TupleElementTypes()
        items := make([]hclwrite.Tokens, len(etys))
        for i, ety := range etys {
            items[i] = typeExprTokens(ety)
        }
        return hclwrite.TokensForTuple(items)
    }

    panic(fmt.Errorf("unsupported type %#v", ty))
}
```

This program will generate the same output as the previous example. You can change `func main` to pass a different type to `typeExprTokens` to see how it behaves with some different types.

Comment: Awesome, thank you soo sooo much. This code works like a charm and it has helped me a great deal to overcome a blocker. Thanks a ton, once again. 

Comment: @MohammedSaaduddinAnsari As I predicted: Mart wrote a better answer than I would have attempted. Please upvote and accept it if was helpful to you (as you seem to indicate it was).

Comment: @MattSchuchard , Yes it helped me alot. Thanks Mart for such great answer.

However, I still am stuck with another thing - where I need to figure out the type of each attribute and associate it with the cty.Type . 

I have posted another question : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74378542/fetch-attribute-type-from-terraform-provider-schema 

Is it possible for you guys to take a look please. I really need help on this.